# How to add a transition effect for this read more/ read less function

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I created a function to calculate the different heights of 2 divs to get a reference height and then add that height to a div to hide a certain amount of the paragraph text. The div then expands the content when the read more is clicked on and vice versa. However I am having issues trying to add a transition effect to the div when it expands and collapses. I tried by using  `textElement.style.transition = 'height 2s ease` which has no effect.

HTML

```
<section class="productInfo">
  <div id="x">Breadcrumbs</div>
  <div class="product-name">Name</div>
  <div class="price"></div>
  <div class="product-descrip">
    <h2 id="y">Description</h2>
    <div class="text cut-off show-more-height toggle">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi id ultricies ligula. Duis quam nisi, tristique vitae vestibulum in, lobortis at sapien. Nullam porttitor congue elementum. Suspendisse nec ornare metus, non molestie massa. Proin ut sem ullamcorper, fermentum leo sed, hendrerit risus. Phasellus fringilla magna non mauris sodales, ac maximus turpis volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent maximus luctus diam. Nulla quam magna, efficitur in orci at, dignissim suscipit elit. Etiam consequat congue massa, eget suscipit lacus lobortis ullamcorper.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi id ultricies ligula. Duis quam nisi, tristique vitae vestibulum in, lobortis at sapien. Nullam porttitor congue elementum. Suspendisse nec ornare metus, non molestie massa. Proin ut sem ullamcorper, fermentum leo sed, hendrerit risus. Phasellus fringilla magna non mauris sodales, ac maximus turpis volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent maximus luctus diam. Nulla quam magna, efficitur in orci at, dignissim suscipit elit. Etiam consequat congue massa, eget suscipit lacus lobortis ullamcorper.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi id ultricies ligula. Duis quam nisi, tristique vitae vestibulum in, lobortis at sapien. Nullam porttitor congue elementum. Suspendisse nec ornare metus, non molestie massa. Proin ut sem ullamcorper, fermentum leo sed, hendrerit risus. Phasellus fringilla magna non mauris sodales, ac maximus turpis volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent maximus luctus diam. Nulla quam magna, efficitur in orci at, dignissim suscipit elit. Etiam consequat congue massa, eget suscipit lacus lobortis ullamcorper.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex test">
            <h2 class="dropdown-header show-more">Read More</h2>
           
          </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.productInfo {
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  transition: height 2s ease;
}
.cut-off {
    --mask: linear-gradient(
            to bottom,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 60%,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 95%,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0
        )
        100% 50% / 100% 100% repeat-x;

    -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
     mask: var(--mask);
}
```

JavaScript

```
distY = y.offsetTop - x.offsetTop;
// alert(Math.floor(distY));
console.log(Math.floor(distY));
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var x = document.getElementById("x");
    var y = document.getElementById("y");
    var target = document.querySelector(".show-more-height");
    var showMoreButton = document.querySelector(".test");
    var updatedHeight;

    function adjustHeight() {
        var referenceHeight = y.offsetTop - x.offsetTop;
        console.log(referenceHeight);
        if (referenceHeight <= 50) {
            updatedHeight = referenceHeight + "px";
            target.style.height = updatedHeight;
        } else {
            updatedHeight = referenceHeight + "px";
            target.style.height = updatedHeight;
        }

        return updatedHeight;
    }

    adjustHeight();

    // window.addEventListener('resize', adjustHeight);

    // Read more event
    var showMoreButton = document.querySelector(".show-more");
    var textElement = document.querySelector(".text");
    var adjHeight = adjustHeight();

    showMoreButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (textElement.classList.contains("show-more-height")) {
            showMoreButton.textContent = "Read Less";
            textElement.style.height = null;
            textElement.style.transition = 'max-height 2s ease';
          target.style.transition = 'max-height 2s ease';
            target.classList.remove("cut-off");
        } else {
            showMoreButton.textContent = "Read More";
            textElement.style.height = adjHeight;
            textElement.style.transition = 'max-height 2s ease';
            target.style.transition = 'max-height 2s ease';
            console.log(adjHeight)
            target.classList.add("cut-off");
        }

        textElement.classList.toggle("show-more-height");
    });
});
```

Can anyone tell me another way to achieve a transition ease effect and what I am doing wrong? Here is the link to the codepen https://codepen.io/Dayz13/pen/MWzpNON

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use max-height instead of height

Comment: Please note that [providing a link to your site is not sufficient](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428). Paste your code here as text so as to make a [mre].

Comment: Set an initial height in your .text class

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Gerard, you need to use `max-height` instead of `height`.

You could try something like this:

- Use the `scrollHeight` property of the text block you want to animate and use it as the `max-height` property on the `.collapsible` element. It stores the height of the DOM element and is not affected by the overflow property.
- Toggle the `.collapsed` class on the `.collapsible` element. When it's present, it'll enforce the `max-height` of whatever value you prefer. When it's removed, the `max-height` value of the DOM element will be used instead.

```js
const toggleElement = document.querySelector('#read-more-toggle')

const collapsibleElement = document.querySelector('.collapsible');

toggleElement.onclick = () => collapsibleElement.classList.toggle('collapsed');

collapsibleElement.style.maxHeight = `${collapsibleElement.scrollHeight}px`;
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.collapsible {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.collapsed {
  max-height: 100px !important;
  --mask: linear-gradient( to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 60%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 95%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0) 100% 50% / 100% 100% repeat-x;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
  mask: var(--mask);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Description</h2>

  <div class="collapsible collapsed">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi id ultricies ligula. Duis quam nisi, tristique vitae vestibulum in, lobortis at sapien. Nullam porttitor congue elementum. Suspendisse nec ornare metus, non molestie massa. Proin ut sem
      ullamcorper, fermentum leo sed, hendrerit risus. Phasellus fringilla magna non mauris sodales, ac maximus turpis volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent maximus luctus diam. Nulla
      quam magna, efficitur in orci at, dignissim suscipit elit. Etiam consequat congue massa, eget suscipit lacus lobortis ullamcorper.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi id ultricies ligula. Duis quam nisi, tristique vitae vestibulum in, lobortis at sapien. Nullam porttitor congue elementum. Suspendisse nec ornare metus, non molestie massa. Proin ut sem
      ullamcorper, fermentum leo sed, hendrerit risus. Phasellus fringilla magna non mauris sodales, ac maximus turpis volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent maximus luctus diam. Nulla
      quam magna, efficitur in orci at, dignissim suscipit elit. Etiam consequat congue massa, eget suscipit lacus lobortis ullamcorper.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi id ultricies ligula. Duis quam nisi, tristique vitae vestibulum in, lobortis at sapien. Nullam porttitor congue elementum. Suspendisse nec ornare metus, non molestie massa. Proin ut sem
      ullamcorper, fermentum leo sed, hendrerit risus. Phasellus fringilla magna non mauris sodales, ac maximus turpis volutpat. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent maximus luctus diam. Nulla
      quam magna, efficitur in orci at, dignissim suscipit elit. Etiam consequat congue massa, eget suscipit lacus lobortis ullamcorper.</p>
  </div>
  <button id="read-more-toggle">Read More</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It kind of works, however I cannot set the max-height to one value in collapsed as that height would be adjusted in the function above. Also cannot update that height from the function because the inline style of max-height would cancel each other out